# PHP session and/or variables expiring early

Tags: php, session, google-api-php-client

I have some code that does the following:

1. Starts a session
2. Creates an rtf document from form data
3. Saves the form as `$file_name.rtf`
4. Authorizes with Google Drive (Google Account sign-in required if not already signed in)
5. Possible ends the session if not signed in?
6. Uploads and converts the `rtf` file from the server to the user's Google Drive folder.

   - Case 1.  Already signed in: Everything works perfectly.
   - Case 2.  Not yet signed in: The `rtf` document is created perfectly but variables like `$file_name` are lost so an empty file is uploaded
     to google drive. The `$file_date variable`, however, remains.

I am wondering why this code doesn't work if a user is not yet signed in. I suspect it has something to do with this section of the Google API Client:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token ']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure what needs to be changed for this to work after sign in.

Simplified code is below:

```
<?php

session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once $dir . '/../../lib/PHPRtfLite.php';

// register PHPRtfLite class loader
PHPRtfLite::registerAutoloader();

// Bunch of code that creates an RTF document

// Save rtf document
$file_date = date("n.j.y");
$file_name = $file_date . " - " . $invoice_number . " - " . $customer_name;
$rtf->save($dir . '/' . $file_name . '.rtf');

?>

// Begin Google API Client

<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
include_once "templates/base.php";


set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

  DEFINE("APPRAISAL", $file_name . '.rtf');


$client_id = 'xxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxxx';
$redirect_uri = 'xxxx';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token ']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

/************************************************
  If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
  file.
 ************************************************/
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->title = $file_name;
  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

  // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
  $client->setDefer(true);
  $request = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'convert' => true
));

  // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
  $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
      $client,
      $request,
      'application/rtf',
      null,
      true,
      $chunkSizeBytes
  );
  $media->setFileSize(filesize(APPRAISAL));

  // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
  // complete.
  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen(APPRAISAL, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  }

  // The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
  // that has been uploaded.
  $result = false;
  if ($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
  }

  fclose($handle);
}

echo pageHeader("File Upload - Appraisal");

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Congradulations!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="request">
          <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
            <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <?php if (isset($result) && $result): ?>
          <div>
            <p>The link to the document is: <a href="<?php echo $result["alternateLink"]; ?>"><?php echo $file_name; ?></a></p>
          </div>
        <?php endif ?>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it vary between case 1 and case 2? I.e. does case 1 happen sometimes but 2 some other times?

Comment: There is a third case, Fatal Error: Missing refresh token. I think I can figure that out.  But besides that, it's either case 1 or case 2.

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional space `' '` here:

```
$_SESSION['upload_token '])
```

I'm quite sure this could affect the code.

You're basically un-setting a session that was never set in the first place, not un-setting `$_SESSION['upload_token']` at all.

Perhaps there's more to it, but this should be a good start.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a feeling there is more to it as well since this was just used to unset a session, but like you said, it's a good start.